# Accessing jQuery UI Tabs inside an iFrame

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using a jQuery UI Tabs widget that exists within an iframe on the page. From the parent document, I need to be able to access the tabs object and use its methods (the 'select' method in particular). I am using the following code currently:

```
var iframe = $('#mainFrame').contents().get(0);
$('#tabs', iframe).tabs('select', 1);
```

The code does not throw any errors/warnings in the console and the jquery object for $('#tabs', iframe) does seem to be selecting the correct elements from the DOM of the iframe, however nothing happens when this is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're turning the jQuery object reference into a `DOM node` by calling `.get(0)`. Try instead:

```
var iframe = $('#mainFrame').contents();
iframe.find('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
```

ref.: [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try (untested):

```
$('#mainFrame').contents().find('#tabs').tabs('select', 1);
```